# Is there any way to remove the application warning in firefox?

Tags: html, firefox

Currently when we use application cache, the firefox brower shows a warning 'This website() is asking to store data on your computer for offline use' . 
with options : 1.Allow 2. Never for this website 3. Not now .
If we choose to ignore the warning , application cache does not work and new changes do not get shown i n the application. Is there any way at the application level to ovveride this warning message?

Answer (score 0):

you realy can't bypass firefox warning . Only if the firefox user uncheck the option " `Tell me when a website asks to store data for offline use` " in network tab in the Advanced setting . good luck